# Using yFiles layouts in cytoscape.js

Tags: json, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, yfiles

I am new to cytoscape.js. I want to use hierarchical layout from yFiles layouts in cytoscape. Is there a way to specify this layout in json file?

Thanks,
Rtut

Answer (score -1):

You can make a layout [extension](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) using the yFiles algorithm.  That will make the yFiles layout a reusable Cytoscape layout.  You could alternatively just update the positions ad-hoc based on yFiles output, but it's really easy and beneficial to make an extension.

If you just want to specify positions at init: Nodes are positioned wherever you specify in the `position` field in the [element JSON](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

You can call `node.position()` or `nodes.positions()` on elements that already exist.  Layout extensions tend to use `nodes.positions()` (more manual)  or `nodes.layoutPositions()` (easier).

If you do decide to make an extension, please publish it.  The process of building and publishing an extension is [fully automated](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/autoscaffolding), so it gives you nice modularity and it gives other devs the opportunity to try out and contribute to your layout.